# Adding to MAMP database in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I made a program that pulls questions from a database for people to answer.
When they answer correctly the next question button pops up.
It also needs to increase the score of that user by 1, how do I tell it to do that?

[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf3Ra.jpg)

```
if($answer === $dbanswer) {
        echo "correct! (creates button that goes to Next Question)

   //This is the part I want working.   

   UPDATE users   
   SET score = score + 1    
   WHERE id = this user's id

} else
   echo "incorrect, try again ";
```

Comment: Can you tell use a little bit more about how you want this thing to work in the end? Example: You could have a script question.php?question=123 where you show the question. The answer could be a POST to answer.php where you evaluate and on success relocate to the next question.php?question=124. Another way would be to use Ajax. You could even put all questions on the same page and hide/show them using pure javascipt. It all depends on what you want and your experience level.

Comment: I already have a system where questions are stored in a database and I'm not planning to change that, could you show how to do it with a fixed ID?

Comment: Without knowing how you did/want this to be structured, it's pretty much impossible to answer your question. To simply output a button that goes to the next question: `echo '<button type="button" onclick="location.href=question.php?id=', $nextQuestionId, '">next question</button>';` or make a link: `echo '<a href="question.php?id=', $nextQuestionId, '">next question</a>';` or relocate to the next question: `header("Location: question.php?id=$nextQuestionId");`